# MutationObserver listen even if was never called

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am programing an external script. I need to add some elements in a section that is cleared every 30 seconds. So I bound `MutationObserver` that restores content after it's wiped. While testing I notice that my `MutationObserver` working even if I never call him.

Here is my code for creating my element:

```
function moveFilters(){
   if($("#new-filter-place").length == 0){
       $("<h1 id='new-filter-place'>TEST</h1>").insertAfter($('#category-top10'));
       observeFilters();
   }
}
```

Here is my observer:

```
function observeFilters(){
    console.log('test');
    var target = document.querySelector("#new-filter-place");
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations){
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation){
            var nodes = Array.from(mutation.removedNodes);
            var directMatch = nodes.indexOf(target) > -1;
            var parentMatch = nodes.some(parent => parent.contains(target));
            if(directMatch || parentMatch){
                observer.disconnect();
                moveFilters();
        }
    });
})
var config = {
    subtree: true,
    childList: true
};
    observer.observe(document.body, config);
}
```

I never called function `moveFilters` nor `observeFilters`, so there is no element with id "new-filter-place" on the page, but when other elements are wiped observer is triggered.

Can someone explain to me how the function can be triggered when I never call it?

Comment: The only explanation is that you actually call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, after hours and hours of debuging i found it. There was other script wrote down by other programmer, so basicly he called that script.